# Meaning of values received from "SecTrustCopyPublicKey" call

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https, nsurlsession

When making a HTTPS request to google.com, I did the following:

```
import Foundation

class LearnNSURLSession: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        let mySession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let data = mySession.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!, completionHandler: myHandler)
        data.resume()
    }

    func myHandler(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void {
        let s = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        println(s)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        println("ERROR:  \(error)")
    }

    // Handles HTTPS connections
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
        println("\nPublic KEY:  \(SecTrustCopyPublicKey(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust).takeUnretainedValue())")
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.PerformDefaultHandling, nil)
    }

    // Handles redirection
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(request)
    }
```

When I run the code, I notice that `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge` gets called twice and I get the following outputs from the `println("Public KEY:\(SecTrustCopyPublicKey(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust).takeUnretainedValue())")`:

```
Public KEY:  <SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPublicKey, version: 3, block size: 2048 bits, exponent: {hex: 10001, decimal: 65537}, modulus: 982A37418AF3B46A9C0BDC42520DD4EFE3854B118194B8A199ACE499B8B3FF8F566360E0DCF44659AA2BB07CCAD187FB9238C925B2F1F7864492BF79F99DE9DD8F8CFB6D868C5DCA4146D78BA33182FC4FE54D9C68B14F3D13795FAAA20A5133B73D1FEBD1AD1B12B2010A8687D6848335A1C0BA4FCBF530A098EE16C22EEBE21D5DD8C296ECA39501B3D1A8848DEC265B9A1F63D95C852040B40A5B2E7712D8A24CAC67245D9AD3A8D9446E26905A4D8A2002876659BFE9204D30A08CBC49095FF3045C33E52C20FD6EA6FD5DD7E9F61E103190BE46638C0FBD43CCE88242020395921C7542F59D17E63BEB17C95798E45DEB989610B672294A856BF1F6667B, addr: 0x7f96fb044000>

Public KEY:  <SecKeyRef curve type: kSecECCurveSecp256r1, algorithm id: 3, key type: ECPublicKey, version: 3, block size: 256 bits, y: Value1, x: Value2, addr: 0x7f96fc032970>
```

I have ommited the values of "y" and "x" in the second output, because I don't know if I should post them. The "Value1" (y) is a string with 66 characters and "Value2" (x) is a string with 130 characters. Both only have numbers and upper-case letter, no symbols.

What are the "x" and "y" values in the second output? Are they the "subjectPublicKeyInfo"? Why is this function called twice? And why I must call "SecTrustEvaluate" before calling "SecTrustCopyPublicKey"? The documentation said I must do so, but I couldn't find why. Also, does iOS automatically do what "SecTrustEvaluate" does, when a HTTPS connection is being established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the "x" and "y" values in the second output?

The parameters of the elliptic curve that is being used. Basically, "the public key." For your purposes, you don't need to know the math, but accept that there are two very large numbers that when put into a formula for an mathematical curve can be used to encrypt data that only the sender can decrypt, or symmetrically, to verify that data was sent by the given sender. If you care, [here's](http://www.embedded.com/design/safety-and-security/4396040/An-Introduction-to-Elliptic-Curve-Cryptography) a reasonably useful introduction to the concept. It's difficult to explain without some math, but the math in that paper isn't too crazy.

The "numbers and letters" are just the hexidecimal encoding of two massive numbers. It's the same as the "modulus" in the other key you list. That's a different algorithm, called RSA. In that case, that's a (really incredibly huge) number that will be used as the modulus (number you divide by and take the remainder) in one of the steps.

All of these numbers are public. There are no secrets here.

> Why is this function called twice?

It starts out negotiating RSA. Then it looks like it upgrades to elliptic curve, which is generally stronger for a given number of bits in your key. Short answer: "protocol upgrade."

> And why I must call "SecTrustEvaluate" before calling "SecTrustCopyPublicKey"?

`SecTrustEvaluate` does a bunch of decoding that is necessary before the public key is available in the data structure. "Because Security.Framework is implemented that way." In theory, `SecTrustCopyPublicKey` could do the decoding if necessary, but it doesn't.

> Also, does iOS automatically do what "SecTrustEvaluate" does, when a HTTPS connection is being established?

Yes.

Comment: `The parameters of the elliptic curve that is being used. Basically, "the public key."` These are the parameters I use to do public key pinning? And is "y" or "x" the pseudo-random 256-bit key that the client creates, encrypts with the server public key and send it back to the server, as described here? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19473/understanding-2048-bit-ssl-and-256-bit-encryption

Comment: No, you typically pin to the full X.509 certificate rather than just the key. For an intro to the topic w/ code for iOS see http://robnapier.net/pinning-your-ssl-certs. And, no, "y" and "x" are not that key. "x" and "y" are part of the server's public key, given the output you've printed. The session key (the one you're probably talking about) is different and very secret (also, isn't computed at the point you're investigating).

Comment: I've read about certificate pinning, but after reading the OWASP guide to SSL pinning, I've decided to use Public Key Pinning using the "subjectPublicKeyInfo". Do you have any material about that?

Comment: I don't. Why do you want to pin to the public key rather than the full cert? iOS gives good mechanisms for working with certs at a high level, but as you dig deeper, Security.Framework often doesn't have the feature you'd want. Are you rotating a certificate with a constant public key?

Comment: I did some reading about SSL certificates and I was wrong about the certificate content. I thought the certificate contained the public and the private keys, but looks like it only stores the public one. So I was worried about someone using a jailbroken device, dumping the keychain, reading it's content and then stealing the private key. I will pin the certificate. Thanks for the answer and for the link provided.